# How to call a soap web service from JQuery

Tags: java, html, web-services, jquery

I have developed a sample application for calling soap web service from JQuery, but I am facing some problem to finding service. I am using apache cxf 2.2.6 jars.

> I used this
>   http://www.local-guru.net/blog/2010/1/24/calling-webservices-from-mootools-jquery-or-dojo
>   to create a webservice cal from JQuery

this is my interface

```
package guru.service;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.xml.ws.RequestWrapper;
@WebService( targetNamespace = "http://www.local-guru.net/helloService" )
public interface HelloService {
    @RequestWrapper( targetNamespace="http://www.local-guru.net/helloService" )
    public String hello(@WebParam( name="givenname", targetNamespace="http://www.local-guru.net/helloService"  ) String givenname, @WebParam( name="name", targetNamespace="http://www.local-guru.net/helloService" ) String name );
}
```

My implementation class is

```
package guru.service;
import javax.jws.WebService;
@WebService( endpointInterface="guru.service.HelloService", serviceName="HelloService", targetNamespace = "http://www.local-guru.net/helloService" )
public class HelloServiceImpl implements HelloService{
    public String hello( String givenname, String name ) {
        return "Hello " + givenname + " " + name + "!";
    }
}
```

And My application context

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">   
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />           
    <bean id="helloServiceImpl" class="guru.service.HelloServiceImpl" />    
        <jaxws:endpoint id="helloService" 
        implementor="#helloServiceImpl" address="/helloService"/>        
</beans>
```

I can see my WSDl definition by using this URL

> http://192.168.1.209:8080/sampleWebService/helloService?wsdl

Using soapUI 3.6.1 software I created soap request for this service

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:hel="http://www.local-guru.net/helloService">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <hel:hello>         
         <hel:givenname>MAYA</hel:givenname>         
         <hel:name>MANI</hel:name>
      </hel:hello>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My Service response is

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:helloResponse xmlns:ns2="http://www.local-guru.net/helloService">
         <return>Hello MAYA MANI!</return>
      </ns2:helloResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

but when I try to call my service using jquery, I get this error

> WARNING: Interceptor for
>   {http://www.local-guru.net/helloService}HelloService has thrown
>   exception, unwinding now org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Error
>   reading XMLStreamReader.  at
>   org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor.handleMessage(ReadHeadersInterceptor.java:230)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor.handleMessage(ReadHeadersInterceptor.java:60)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletDestination.invoke(ServletDestination.java:98)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:406)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:178)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractCXFServlet.invoke(AbstractCXFServlet.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:179)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doOptions(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:132)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:159)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11Protocol.java:744)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) Caused by:
>   com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog  at
>   [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]     at
>   com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedEOF(StreamScanner.java:686)
>     at
>   com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleEOF(BasicStreamReader.java:2134)
>     at
>   com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2040)
>     at
>   com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1069)
>     at
>   com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextTag(BasicStreamReader.java:1095)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor.handleMessage(ReadHeadersInterceptor.java:122)
>     ... 25 more

And my html page is

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
function callservice() {
    var givenname = $("#givenName").val();
    var name = $("#name").val();

    var q ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:hel="http://www.local-guru.net/helloService"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><hel:hello><hel:givenname>'+givenname+'</hel:givenname><hel:name>'+name+'</hel:name></hel:hello></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>'
           $.ajax({
        url: 'http://192.168.1.209:8080/sampleWebService/helloService/hello',
        data: q,
        type: 'post',
        contentType: 'text/xml; charset="utf-8"',
        success: function(res) {
            $('#result').html(
                res.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://www.local-guru.net/helloService",
                "helloResponse")[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        },

    });
}
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="givenName"/>
        <input type="text" id="name"/>
        <input type="button" onClick="callservice()"/>
    </form>
    <div id="result">result</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: Did you find solution?

Answer (score 1):

from the error you posted it looks to me like the XML payload in your Ajax request is malformed or not what the server expects, have you inspected the request and response in your browser? In situations like this (which often crop up IME) seeing what the difference between your expected SOAP request and what is actually being sent is invaluable.

I would suggest that if the above is true, most likely you have an issue with line endings, or encoding of the "q" string of xml. To test, try something like this: http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_loadxmldoc.asp

Which parses a "well formed" xml file from disk, then sends it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Browser blocks access across domain-boundaries.
Try deploying your HTML page in the webservice domain.

For more info:
http://enable-cors.org/

Comment: Hi luca , I have done, but still the same issue.I have kept my html  into my server only which is running  the web service